# Remove everything from a text except dot , text , number , space

Tags: php

I have this code below

```
 function title($str, $sep=' ')
    {
            $res = strtolower($str);
            $res = preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]]/', ' ', $res);
            $res = preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', $sep, $res);
            return trim($res, $sep);
    }
```

The above codes removes even dots for example

```
$string = title("software[2012] v1.2");
```

results `software v1 2` .but i want like `software v1.2`

Comment: The first `preg_replace` removes everything except letters, numbers, and underscore. That's what `:alnum:` is.

Comment: yea anyway to exlude dot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your regular expressions

The first one (`[^\w\s.]`) will remove anything that is not a charachter, number, space or dot.
The second one (`\s+`) will replace all spaces with your seperator.

```
function title($str, $sep=' ')
{
    $res = strtolower($str);
    $res = preg_replace('/[^\w\s.]/', ' ', $res);
    $res = preg_replace('/\s+/', $sep, $res);
    return trim($res, $sep);
}
```

Comment: No need to escape `.` inside brackets.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the tip, I removed the `\\`

Comment: Also, `\w` includes `\d`, you don't need them both.

Comment: @Jerodev your solution is outputting 'software 2012 v1.2'. See the question, desired output is 'software v1.2'